# place the child element outside of parent in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Place the child node outside of parent node using XSLT.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <p>para content
         <ol>
            <li>li content</li>
            <li>li content</li>
            <li>li content</li>
        </ol>
     Para content continues
  </para>
```

Output

```
   <p>para content Para content continues</p>
   <ol>
            <li>li content</li>
            <li>li content</li>
            <li>li content</li>
  </ol>
```

I have tried with the below code:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="node()"/></p>
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="child::ol">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ol"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>           
</xsl:template>
```

but getting output like:

```
    <p>para content</p>
    <p>para content
</p><ul>
    li content
    li content
    li content
</ul>
```

Para content continues text is missing

Comment: Please show us what you've tried...

Answer (score 2):

Write a template

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and of course start the stylesheet with the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```